# Project issue tracking: How to assign issues to users?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

In my Drupal 7 installation I am using the module [Project issue tracking](https://drupal.org/project/project_issue) together with [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) (every project is a group).

How is it possible that every member of each group is able to assign an issue to any other member of that group? At this moment every user can assign an issue only to him/her self or may set it to ›unassigned‹.

Comment: for D6 check this https://drupal.org/project/issue_assign

Comment: Drupal 7, I added that information to the post. Thank you both.